# User random with html button

Tags: java, html, random, web-applications

i'm using successfully random like this:

```
Random pickName = new Random();
User random = users.get(pickName.nextInt(users.size()));
```

At the moment it shows me the result in my command line everytime i load the page (the random code is in my servlet). My question is:

How can i make a html button which starts the random function and displays me the randomly selected names? Just need an example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have managed bean with java method to fetch random user.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {

   private User randomUser;

   public void fetchRandomUser() {
      Random pickName = new Random();
      randomUser = users.get(pickName.nextInt(users.size()));
   }

   //getters and setters
}
```

and then you have your `.xhtml` page with fragment:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.randomUser.name}" id="random_user"/>
<h:commandButton value="Pick random user" action="#{myBean.fetchRandomUser()}" update="random_user"/>
```

Of course it's just an example and I could make some mistakes but I think it should help you to start.